# Как изменить checkbox после редиректа?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Есть 2 страницы. Первая содержит в себе одну кнопку, а вторая один checkbox (по умолчанию он не нажат). Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку сделать редирект на вторую страницу (например через window.location) и активировать checkbox. Уже подсказали, что можно использовать data атрибуты, но все равно не очень понимаю, как активировать checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Этого можно легко добиться с помощью аргументов URL'a. На первой странице к адресу ссылки добавляем параметр, например: `.../view_page?need_check=1`

На второй странице с помощью JavaScript'a проверяем параметр и при его наличии ставим галку в чекбоксе:

```
// просто функция для извлечения аргумента url'a
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

// извлекаем и проверяем параметр
var need_check = false;
if (window.location.href.includes('need_check'))
    need_check = +getUrlParameter('need_check') > 0;

// устанавливаем значение чекбокса
$("#ch_split").prop("checked", need_check);
```